# My model name is changed as TimeBase to TimeBasis. NameError in AdminsController#destroy uninitialized constant User::TimeBasis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

My model name is changed to TimeBase to TimeBasis and when i delete a user record in the other table and getting below error.
NameError in AdminsController#destroy  uninitialized constant User::TimeBasis.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post controller source and error log  ?

Comment: Did you change time_base.rb file name to time_basis.rb?

Comment: Could be a few things - did you change to TimeBasis in the User Model for the belongs_to/has_many relationship?  Also, you need to change the time_base_id column in the Users table.